# Finding jar with given class by name in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

While debugging a very difficult classpath problem, I dumped SBT compile classpath. What I need to find is what jar file (in classpath) a class name belongs to.

Is this do-able in SBT? Or is there a mechanism in Scala that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-verbose:class` in **Java** is the approach ["to display the information about classes being loaded by JVM."](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-use-verbose-options-java). I haven't used it with **Scala**, but it could work since JVM's involved after all.

Use `-verbose:class` with `javaOptions` in SBT and then parse the output.